# Why coredata is returning null array while I am inserting values in table

Tags: ios, core-data

I have two methods,

In first method, I do save values in Core Data, while in other, I simply fetch them.

After inserting, when I fetch data in same method, it shows value, but when I try to fetch in other method if returns me null.

My saving Method is

```
-(void) saveloginData:(NSString *)facebookTok username:(NSString *)userName password:(NSString*)password flag:(NSString *)flag {


NSError *error;

NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];



NSFetchRequest * fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[fetchRequest setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"SignIn" inManagedObjectContext:context]];
[fetchRequest setIncludesPropertyValues:NO]; //only fetch the managedObjectID

NSString *facebookTokenData = facebookTok;
NSString *usernameData = userName;
NSString *passwordData = password;
NSString *flagData = flag;


NSLog(@"Facebook Token%@\nUsername%@\npassword%@\nflat%@\n",facebookTokenData,usernameData,passwordData,flagData);


SignIn *signIn = [NSEntityDescription
                                        insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"SignIn"
                                        inManagedObjectContext:context];

signIn.facebookToken = facebookTokenData;
signIn.username = usernameData;
signIn.password = passwordData;
signIn.flag = flagData;


NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"SignIn"
                                          inManagedObjectContext:context];

[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

NSArray *fetchedArray = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];


for (SignIn *info in fetchedArray) { 
            \\ THis executes and shows values, proves that value are inserted.

    NSLog(@"Name  ~~~~ : %@", info.username);
    NSLog(@"Password ~~~~~~~~ :%@", info.password);
    NSLog(@"FLAG ~~~~~~~~~~~ %@",info.flag);
    NSLog(@"Facebook Token %@", info.facebookToken);
}
}
```

My retrieve Method is

```
-(NSArray*) getLoginData {

NSError *error;

NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"SignIn"
                                          inManagedObjectContext:context];


[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

NSArray *fetchedData = [[NSArray alloc] init];


fetchedData = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

NSLog(@"The count of Array %d", [fetchedData count]); \\ HERE COUNT IS ZERO, WHY?


for (SignIn *info in fetchedData) {
    NSLog(@" FF    Name  ~~~~ : %@", info.username);
    NSLog(@"Password ~~~~~~~~ :%@", info.password);
    NSLog(@"FLAG ~~~~~~~~~~~ %@",info.flag);
    NSLog(@"Facebook Token %@", info.facebookToken);
}


return fetchedData;
 }
```

Please guide that where I am doing mistake.

Comment: Is the managed object context the same in both methods?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that you need to save conext to get the entity it later.

`NSManagedObjectContext save:` Attempts to commit unsaved changes to registered objects to their persistent store.

```
- (BOOL)save:(NSError **)error
```

Parameters: `error`: A pointer to an `NSError` object. You do not need to create an `NSError` object. The save operation aborts after the first failure if you pass `NULL`.

Return Value `YES` if the save succeeds, otherwise `NO`.

So you need to save context after you modify your object:

```
signIn.facebookToken = facebookTokenData;
signIn.username = usernameData;
signIn.password = passwordData;
signIn.flag = flagData;

[context save:NULL]; // NULL if you don't need to handle error
```